# Using 2 observables with 1 output observable

Tags: rxjs

How can I have these 2 observables `streamA$` and `streamB$` run concurrently with click events?

The code I've got doesn't work properly: if I click A, then B while A is still in progress, B cancels A and vice versa. How can I have the 2 in parallel so if I click B while A is in progress, A continues and the result is assigned to `images$` then if B finishes after, it replaces images$ so 2 results would appear in sequence. Then I could use waitUntil, filters etc to managae the 2 streams.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.streamA$ = this.streamService.getStream(1);
    this.streamB$ = this.streamService.getSlowStream(2);
  }

  clickA() {
    this.images$ = this.streamA$;
  }

  clickB() {
    this.images$ = this.streamB$;
  }
```

Template, subscribes to images$ with async

```
<div class="section">
    {{images$ | async}}
</div>
```

Comment: result need to append or replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a queue subject and concatMap you stream, it'll process in sequence and never miss any click.

```
private queue = new Subject()
public images$ = queue.pipe(concatMap(res => res))

clickA(){
  this.queue.next(this.streamA$)
}

clickB(){
  this.queue.next(this.streamB$)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4zmd6

Comment: why do you have queue = new Subject() outside the functions

Comment: queue is a private property in your class. maybe i should edit that

Comment: should queue use the queue$ variable style

Comment: Personal preference really. I use mostly stream so might as well skip $

Comment: it didn't work, I click a button and it gets data, if I click again it doesn't work

Comment: Do u have a stackbliz ?

Comment: provided a stackbliz example

Comment: I've done a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-queue, not sure why it's not working with mine. I'm return an observable with timer from a service.

Comment: did you check out the stackbliz i posted in the answer?

Comment: yes, mine is almost the same, don't know why mines not working

Comment: need to use concatMap. and your streamA and B not setup to emit anything. that's why

Comment: You should use merge instead. And use a `merge` creational operator, not the mapping `mergeMap` or `concatMap`

Comment: Why use that over Subject()? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @FanCheung I've updated the stackblitz, I think I've setup the streams correctly but it's still not working, it only works once any clicks following first don't do anything

Comment: tried your example. It remembers every click you've done, why you think it's not working?